# SQL - Show 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I would like to display a table with the following columns:

| SKU | Inventory in WarehouseA | Inventory in WarehouseB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | 20 |

Below is my current query:

```
select a.ItemID, SUM(a.Quantity), b.WarehouseDescription
from dbo.a

INNER JOIN dbo.b on a.WarehouseID = b.WarehouseID

GROUP BY a.ItemID, b.WarehouseDescription
HAVING a.Quantity <>0
and b.WarehouseDescription = 'WarehouseA'
and b.WarehouseDescription = 'WarehouseB'
ORDER BY a.ItemID, b.WarehouseDescription
```

The output generated so far follows this form:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SKU | Inventory in WarehouseA | Warehouse A |
| SKU | Inventory in Warehouse B | Warehouse B |
| 123 | 10 | Warehouse A |
| 123 | 20 | Warehouse B |

Feedback/constructive comments are welcome!

Comment: I doubt that query returns that result set. Seems like, however, what you want is conditional aggregation or a `PIVOT`.

Comment: There is no chance you are getting that output from the query you posted. There are no rows in your table where the description equals both of those values at the same time. I also suspect you want to use HAVING a.Quantity <> 0 instead of the where clause.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, that's correct, I was wondering if a PIVOT on excel can be performed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly guessing here as we don't have much detail to work with. But something like this is how you might tackle conditional aggregation for this.

```
select a.ItemID
    , WarehouseA = SUM(case when b.WarehouseDescription = 'WarehouseA' then a.Quantity else 0 end)
    , WarehouseB = SUM(case when b.WarehouseDescription = 'WarehouseB' then a.Quantity else 0 end)
from dbo.a
INNER JOIN dbo.b on a.WarehouseID = b.WarehouseID
where b.WarehouseDescription in ('WarehouseA', 'WarehouseB')
GROUP BY a.ItemID
HAVING a.Quantity <>0
ORDER BY a.ItemID
    , b.WarehouseDescription
```